# What does "commit a minimum of four weeks" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Does "one must commit a minimum of four weeks (or at least $2,000)" mean "customers must use their service at least 4 times"?

Eater's Ryan Sutton reported that the Italian restaurant Carbone now offers a Hamptons pickup service that starts at $500 per week, though one must commit a minimum of four weeks (or at least $2,000).

Source:https://www.businessinsider.com/wealthy-not-spending-as-much-money-coronavirus-pandemic-economy-2020-6

Comment: I doubt that is true. Here is the restaurant on Long Island (the Hamptons) and it does not mention that price. https://www.exploretock.com/carbone-hamptons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the service should be bought for at least 4 weeks.

The service provider decides whether they want you to pay for the four weeks in advance or sign agreement where they clearly mention what's going to happen if you cancel the service before the fourth week.

Comment: "Carbone now offers a Hamptons pickup service" 
I assume the restaurant is the service provider here.

Comment: Thanks Lambie, I changed it to the "decides", I guess that sounds better.

Comment: NY is such a rip-off place. And the Hamptons on Long Island is only for the very rich. I am so happy to not live in NYC anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Does "one must commit a minimum of four weeks (or at least $2,000)" mean "customers must use their service at least 4 times"?

**NO**- it indicates that the service is 4 weeks in duration at a cost of $2000.

Using "the service" 4 times would mean four 4-week commitments at $2000 each.

The breakdown of weekly cost of $500 is basically unnecessary.